# Как сделать ресайз картинок с s3 хранилища на лету с помощью nginx?

Tags: nginx, resize, s3

Сейчас храню картинки на диске и довольно успешно использую модуль ngx_http_image_filter_module для изменения размеров картинок. Но появилась необходимость вынести картинки в s3 хранилище, что делает невозможным использование модуля nginx в том же виде.

Есть возможность подключить s3 прокси вроде такого докер образа pottava/s3-proxy, но кажется, что ngx_http_image_filter_module не может обрабатывать картинки из такого upstream.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли оставить ресайз на стороне nginx при переходе на s3?
Или какое-то другое решение, которое справляется с задачей на s3 хранилищах.

Comment: Может что-то [такое](https://github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-image-resizing).

Comment: @Rudi если я правильно понял, это решение для Aws? У меня хостер дает s3, но я не в aws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение на go https://docs.imgproxy.net/

Можно подключать в качестве контейнера в docker, либо устанавливать на сервер.

Со стороны бэкенда формирую ссылку для imageproxy и передаю в nginx чтобы он вернул данные из upstream, на котором висит imageproxy.